Properties ['date_picker_efd'] passed to __init__ may not be existing property names
I want to use MDDatePicker() inside MDDialog(). For that, I assign to content_cls a class(AddDocumentDialog)  that inherits from MDBoxLayout, but it results in the error that  I show the following:
class AddDocumentDialog(MDBoxLayout):
   def __int__(self, **kw):
      super(AddDocumentDialog, self).__init__(**kw)
      self.ids.date_picker_efd.on_release = kw["date_picker_efd"]


def show_add_document_dialog(self):
    if not self.add_document_dialog:
        self.add_document_dialog = MDDialog(
            size_hint=(.8, .7),
            title="Add Document:",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=AddDocumentDialog(date_picker_efd=self.show_date_picker),
            buttons=[

TypeError: object.init() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
TypeError: Properties ['date_picker_efd'] passed to init may not be existing property names.
this is a snippet from my kv file:
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    
    MDLabel:
        id: effective_date_label
        size_hint_x: .9
        text: "Effective Date"
        theme_text_color: "Secondary"
        
    MDIconButton:
        id: date_picker_efd
        size_hint_x: .2
        icon: "calendar"

